# MySQL error 2013 with Heidisql but not with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, heidisql

I can't connect to a given database with mysql command line nor heidisql but this is working with mysql workbench.

> SQL Error (2013) in statement #0: Lost connection to MySQL server at
>   'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0

does anybody has a clue what could be the problem ?

Comment: Did you try all the programms from the same box to the same server? The error message seems to indicate that not a single package reached the server (maybe due to a firewall), but that would affect WB as well.

Comment: @MikeLischke yes both programs running on the same machine

Comment: Then the only idea I have is that WB is using a different server/port than the command line or HeidiSQL. Double check all 3 speak to the same server host/port.